# Giving MYSQL error subquery returns more than one rows

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT j. * , w. * 
    FROM tbljobseeker j
    INNER  JOIN tblworkexp w ON j.id = w.userid
    WHERE (
     w.company_name LIKE  '%xoriant%'
    OR w.company_name LIKE  '%XORIANT%'
    OR w.company_name LIKE  '%Xoriant%'
    OR w.company_name LIKE  '%Xoriant%')
     AND (
    w.tomonth !=  'till'
    )
   AND (
   w.fromyear = ( 
   SELECT w.fromyear
    FROM tblworkexp
     WHERE w.tomonth !=  'till'
    ORDER  BY w.fromyear DESC 
     LIMIT 1 , 10 ) 
    )
     ORDER  BY STR_TO_DATE( j.lastModified,  '%e-%M-%Y'  )  DESC , id DESC
```

Please help

Comment: Most implementations of MySQL are case insensitive

Comment: You're saying w.fromyear = [multiple values]
instead of the expected w.fromyear = 2001 ; I did work it out as answer for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Change that `w.fromyear =` to `w.fromyear in`. That will solve the issue.

To explain, your limit clause `LIMIT 1 , 10` saying that get me 10 records starting from 1st record.

with `=` operator, you can only check single value and not multiple value. To check against multiple value you need to use `in` operator like `in (val1,val2,val3, ..., valn)`

So, your sub query in post should look like

```
AND (
   w.fromyear in ( 
   SELECT w.fromyear
    FROM tblworkexp
     WHERE w.tomonth !=  'till'
    ORDER  BY w.fromyear DESC 
     LIMIT 1 , 10 ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning multiple values, where only one is expected.

This will work, as it will check for a range now:

```
SELECT j. * , w. * 
    FROM tbljobseeker j
    INNER  JOIN tblworkexp w ON j.id = w.userid
    WHERE (
     w.company_name LIKE  '%xoriant%'
    OR w.company_name LIKE  '%XORIANT%'
    OR w.company_name LIKE  '%Xoriant%'
    OR w.company_name LIKE  '%Xoriant%')
     AND (
    w.tomonth !=  'till'
    )
   AND (
   w.fromyear in ( 
   SELECT w.fromyear
    FROM tblworkexp
     WHERE w.tomonth !=  'till'
    ORDER  BY w.fromyear DESC 
     LIMIT 1 , 10 ) 
    )
     ORDER  BY STR_TO_DATE( j.lastModified,  '%e-%M-%Y'  )  DESC , id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
   w.fromyear = ( 
   SELECT w.fromyear
    FROM tblworkexp
     WHERE w.tomonth !=  'till'
    ORDER  BY w.fromyear DESC 
     LIMIT 1 , 10 ) 
    )
```

Is not doing what you expect.  It is taking *10* rows from an offset of 1.  So, it is returning more than one row.  Perhaps you intend this, but perhaps you really mean:

```
limit 10, 1
```

or, more clearly written:

```
limit 1 offset 10
```

More importantly, this subquery does not look correct at all, because it never references the inner table.  All the references are to `w`, the outer table.  In fact, it is always returning the outer `w.fromyear`, so the comparison will always be true.

I would suggest that you write another question, with sample data and desired results, to get help on the SQL itself.